# KnockoutJS - observable object doeasn't work

Tags: object, knockout.js, observable

Is it possible to bind unexisting property in observable object? Because after I mapped it I don't see the result.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/66Ton99/wF7xY/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a clean way, but you can do it like this:

```
<div data-bind="text: data().field1 ? data().field1() : ''"></div>​
```

Now (for some reason, not quite sure why) you need to explicitly communicate that the value of the observable has changed and the view should be updated:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(Data, {}, model.data);
model.data.valueHasMutated();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wF7xY/1/

Comment: You don't need expression here <div data-bind="text: data().field1"></div>​

http://jsfiddle.net/66Ton99/wF7xY/2/